# How to use startOfDay from date-fns with timezones?

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I try to replace momentjs with date-fns

but I am struggling with a very simple thing:
I need to calculate startOfDay, end of day and addDays for the dates that I have got in timestamps and according to the giving timezone.

```
date = 1492437600; // Monday April 17, 2017 12:00:00 (pm) in time zone America/Noronha
timeZone = 'America/Noronha';
_startOfDay = utcToZonedTime(startOfDay(date*1000), timeZone).getTime()/1000;
```

and I have got the result for the _startOfDay = 1492365600  that is Sunday April 16, 2017 16:00:00 (pm) in time zone America/Noronha

What I am doing wrong?
thanks in advance

Comment: when you call your method startOfDay(..), you do not specify a timezone so the return date can be the start of Day in any timezone. My guess would be UTC but it could be another timezone.

Answer (score 11):

**Note: See the bottom of this answer for the best solution**

Old Answer:

I see this question is 11 months old (as of writing) but thought I'd answer it as I hit the same problem, and others may come here in the future with the same question.

The *date-fns* library doesn't have timezone support, so you need to also use the *date-fns-tz* library. Import the *getTimezoneOffset* function from *date-fns-tz* and use to calculate the offset between the local (browser) timezone and the timezone you wish to calculate end of day for (i.e. America/Noronha). Note that the *date-fns* "endOf" functions use the local/browser timezone.

E.g.

```
import { endOfDay } from 'date-fns';
import { getTimezoneOffset } from 'date-fns-tz/esm';

const MILLISECS_IN_DAY = 86400000;
            
const localTz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone; // Browser Timezone
const tzOffset = getTimezoneOffset('America/Noronha') - getTimezoneOffset(localTz);

// Have to cater for negative offsets
const tzOffsetEOD = (tzOffset < 0) ? (MILLISECS_IN_DAY + tzOffset) : tzOffset;
       
let testDate = new Date();     
let eodInTimezone = endOfDay(testDate).getTime() - tzOffsetEOD; // in millisecs

// Have to project forward a day if the result is in the past
if (eodInTimezone < testDate.getTime()) eodInTimezone += MILLISECS_IN_DAY;
```

Someone may be able to come up with a more elegant solution to this problem. If I do I'll post back here.

---

New Answer:

This solution works best for all "End Of" *date-fns* functions:

```
import { endOfDay, endOfWeek, endOfMonth, endOfYear } from 'date-fns';
import { utcToZonedTime, zonedTimeToUtc } from 'date-fns-tz/esm';

const calcZonedDate = (date, tz, fn, options = null) => {
    const inputZoned = utcToZonedTime(date, tz);
    const fnZoned = (options) ? fn(inputZoned, options) : fn(inputZoned);
    return zonedTimeToUtc(fnZoned, tz);
}

const getZonedEndOfDay = (date, timeZone) => {
    return calcZonedDate(date, timeZone, endOfDay);
}

const getZonedEndOfWeek = (date, timeZone) => {
    return calcZonedDate(date, timeZone, endOfWeek, { weekStartsOn: 1 });
}

const getZonedEndOfMonth = (date, timeZone) => {
    return calcZonedDate(date, timeZone, endOfMonth);
}

const getZonedEndOfYear = (date, timeZone) => {
    return calcZonedDate(date, timeZone, endOfYear);
}

// Example Usage
let endOfDayZoned = getZonedEndOfDay(new Date(), 'America/Noronha');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to take a look at another date management library. date-fns seems to be designed to work in current timezone and does not provide right tools for timezone calculations.

The same thing in [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon) for example:

```
const startOfDay = DateTime
    .fromMillis(1492437600000)
    .setZone('America/Noronha')
    .startOf('day')
```

Then you can use `startOfDay.toJSDate()` to get Date object with right moment in time, or you could use `startOfDay.toFormat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')` for text output.

Answer (score 0):

startOfDay is now a thing in DateFns.
Example from https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/startOfDay

The start of a day for 2 September 2014 11:55:00:

```js
var result = startOfDay(new Date(2014, 8, 2, 11, 55, 0))
//=> Tue Sep 02 2014 00:00:00
```