# How to calculate the first timestamp/Date of a specific day and the last second's timestamp?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I have a given date as `Date`-object in JavaScript.

From that particular date (e.g. `2024-16-01, 22:35`), I want to go to the beginning of the day (`2024-16-01, 00:00`) and the end of the day (`2024-16-01, 23:59`).

I tried the library `date-fns`, but this gives wrong values.

```
import { addDays, addHours, endOfDay, startOfDay, subHours } from 'date-fns';

// d = new Date(...)
const startDate = subHours(startOfDay(d), hoursBefore);
const endDate = addHours(endOfDay(d), hoursAfter);

console.log('Date: ', d);
console.log('Start Of Day: ', startOfDay(d));
console.log('End Of Day: ', endOfDay(d));
console.log('startDate: ', startDate);
console.log('endDate: ', endDate);
```

Output:

```
Date:  2024-01-16T17:00:00.000Z
Start Of Day:  2024-01-16T17:00:00.000Z
End Of Day:  2024-01-17T16:59:59.999Z
startDate:  2024-01-16T05:00:00.000Z
endDate:  2024-01-17T21:59:59.999Z
```

As one can see, the values are totally different from what they actually should be. Is the timezone playing a disturbing role here? If so, how can I mitigate such risks of getting wrong values?

Or is there another approach how to deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startOfDay` already returns:

> The start of a day

So there is no need to combine it with `subHours` or `addHours`, just do `startOfDay(d)`:

```js
const d = new Date();

const startDate = dateFns.startOfDay(d);
const endDate = dateFns.endOfDay(d);

console.log('Date: ', d);
console.log('Start Of Day: ', startDate);
console.log('End Of Day: ', endDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.28.5/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```

---

Regarding the time-zone, you'll need `date-fns-tz` to convert it relative to your current zone / utc, please refer to:

- [How to use startOfDay from date-fns with timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67819591/how-to-use-startofday-from-date-fns-with-timezones)
- [How to get a start of day date in specific timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75264396/how-to-get-a-start-of-day-date-in-specific-timezone)

Comment: With your example, "Run code snippet", I still get "Start Of Day:  "2024-01-15T17:00:00.000Z". But 17:00:00 is not start of the day.

Comment: Then you're probably in a -7 timezone. [This is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF2OL.png) on GMT+1.

Comment: @delete ... the above example's time offset is due to SO having its own implementations of `console` methods. Thus the experienced offset happens just in the console of the above stack snippet example (, obviously converted to an ISO string) . A parallel opened developer console logs the dates as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Take any passed `Date` object or its parsable string-representation and ...

- create a new `Date` instance and assign it to e.g. a `begins` constant.
- set each of the `begins` date's values (hours, minutes, milli/seconds) to zero.
- add the 24 hours equivalent of milliseconds minus one millisecond to the millisecond of the already computed `begins` date.
- create a new `Date` instance from the computed milliseconds and assign it to e.g. an `ends` constant.

```js
function getDayDataRange(dateOrString) {
  const begins = new Date(
    dateOrString?.getTime?.() ?? String(dateOrString)
  );
  begins.setHours(0);
  begins.setMinutes(0);
  begins.setSeconds(0);
  begins.setMilliseconds(0);

  // - add the 24 hours equivalent of milliseconds minus
  //   one millisecond to the millisecond of the already
  //   computed `begins` date
  // - create a new `Date` instance from the computed milliseconds.

//const ends = new Date(begins.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) - 1)
  const ends = new Date(begins.getTime() + 86400000 - 1);

  return { begins, ends };
}

const { begins, ends } = getDayDataRange("2024-01-16T17:30:59.000Z");

console.log('... work around the SO-specific console-logging ...');
console.log({
  // - Stack Snippets have their own console implementation.
  // - Thus, one needs to (locally) stringify the date objects
  //   before SO console-logging forces an ISO string conversion.
  begins: String(begins),
  ends: String(ends),
});

console.log('... standard console-logging which does work outside of SO ...');
console.log(
  getDayDataRange(new Date)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```